# How to manage flutter state in a clean way?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am new to flutter, trying to learn the state management, I am learning Bloc pattern, and exploring the flutter_block, when observe the state changes at UI layer, we can use `InheritedWidget` like below:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  child: BlocBuilder<RoundBloc, RoundState>(
                      bloc: _roundBloc,
                      builder: (context, state) => _progressIndicator(state))),
              Container(
                  child: BlocBuilder<RoundBloc, RoundState>(
                bloc: _roundBloc,
                builder: (context, state) => _memorizingCards(state),
              )),
              Container(
                  child: BlocBuilder<RoundBloc, RoundState>(
                bloc: _roundBloc,
                builder: (context, state) => _actions(state),
              ))
            ]));
  }

  Widget _progressIndicator(RoundState state) {
    if (state is RoundCreated) {
      return Text('${state.round.memoIndex}/${state.round.cards.length}');
    } else if (state is RoundMemoIndexUpdated) {
      return Text('${state.round.memoIndex}/${state.round.cards.length}');
    } else {
      return Text('0/0');
    }
  }

  Widget _memorizingCards(RoundState state) {
    if (state is RoundCreated) {
      return _carouse(state.round);
    } else if (state is RoundMemoIndexUpdated) {
      return _carouse(state.round);
    } else {
      return poker.Card.back();
    }
  }

  CarouselSlider _carouse(RoundModel round) {
    return CarouselSlider(
        initialPage: 0,
        height: 300,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          _memoIndexUpdate(index, round);
        },
        items: round.cards.map((card) => poker.Card.of(card)).toList());
  }

  Widget _actions(RoundState state) {
    if (state is RoundCreated) {
      return RaisedButton(
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Text('完成'),
          onPressed: _finish(state.round));
    } else {
      return RaisedButton(
        textColor: Colors.white,
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: Text('开始'),
        onPressed: _shuffleCards,
      );
    }
  }

  void _shuffleCards() {
    _roundBloc.add(RoundCreate(RoundModel(shuffledDeck())));
  }

  _finish(RoundModel round) {
    return () => _roundBloc.add(RoundFinishMemo(round));
  }

  void _memoIndexUpdate(int index, RoundModel round) {
    _roundBloc.add(RoundUpdateMemoIndex(round, index));
  }
```

I have to write the BlocBuilder everywhere in my UI code because I want to only updated parts of the UI for a specific state, I am wondering if it's possible I can write code similar with:

```
_roundBloc.listen((state) {
 if (state is RoundCreated) {
   setState(() {
     _localState = state.someValue;
   });
 }
});
```

In this way, my UI code only needs to care about the local state, without wrap the BlocBuilder everywhere, I only listen to bloc state changes and update a local state accordingly.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? why don't you just wrap the top level container in BlockBuilder and pass the state down?

Comment: What's that _localState represents and why do you need setState around?